# hresult 0x800a01b6 on seccond pass

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

I get an *hresult 0x800a01b6* on the seccond passing of my code.

When it runs the first time it works but fails seccond time around. IE opens then program stops.

```
Dim pID As String
        Dim mesg As String
        Dim pw As String
        Dim Id As String
        Dim ie As Object
        Dim l As String

        'For Each Id In ListBox2.Items'
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            Id = Me.ListBox2.Items(i).ToString
            If Id = "me " Then
                Id = "466901"
            ElseIf "you" Then
          Id =  "466942"
            End If
        ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Navigate("http://www.webpage.com.au/")
        ie.Visible = True
            mesg = TextBox1.Text.ToString()
            pw = "....."
            ie.Document.All("password").Value = pw
            ie.Document.All("idpagers").Value = Id
            ie.Document.All("message").Value = mesg
            ie.Document.All("Send").Click()
            pID = ie.Document.All().ToString
            'MessageBox.Show(pID)
            MessageBox.Show(l & mesg & pw, "Test")'
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you want `id="466942"`?

Comment: Fixed missing Id. I need vb code to run as many times as items in my listbox. The fist time runs the seccond time opens IE and i get the error at PW line. Even if i do mesg line first same error